# How to Invoke Firebase in Reactnative app?

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use Firebase Email and password sign in method to create login for my app. when i try to invoke `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` or `signInWithEmailAndPassword` these method are not getting invoked.
How to verify firebase method invocation in reactnative.

```
<Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>Log In</Button> 

onButtonPress(){
    const { email, password } = this.state;

    this.setState({error: ''});
    console.log(email + ' ' + password); //==> this executes
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(function(){
      console.log('sign insuccess'); //==> no execution
    })
    .catch(() => {
      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(function(){
        console.log('create user success'); //==> no execution
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.setState({ error: 'Authentication Failed.' }); //==> no execution
      });
    });
    console.log('buttonpress finished'); 
}
```

[image: error console]

Comment: have you enabled email method in firebase console?

Comment: Have you also done the `Web Setup` step?

Comment: I have added web setup and enabled email and password as sign-in method, but still I couldn't firebase auth invoked

Comment: @PeterHaddad how can I verify if firebase itself intialized I am not able to call any firbase methods in react native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try this it's worked for me, 
hope it'll help you

try `signInAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword` instead of `signInWithEmailAndPassword`

**edited**

`signInAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword` is deprecated now, so you should use   `signInWithEmailAndPassword` otherwise you'll get error.

thank you @mshikher .

Comment: yes signInAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword  worked, idk y signInWithEmailAndPassword didn't work. still its not working.

Comment: After re-installing app signInWithEmailAndPassword also worked.

Comment: firebase.auth.Auth.prototype.signInAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword is deprecated. Please use firebase.auth.Auth.prototype.signInWithEmailAndPassword instead. I am getting this error on using signInAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword

Comment: yes, you are right @mshikher
`signInAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword` is deprecated after September 2018.
now we should use `signInWithEmailAndPassword`.
thank you @mshikher

Comment: does these functions of firebase work with Xcode Emulator?
Whenever I call these functions using firebase library, it gives me an error?

Comment: i have not use these function with Xcode Emulator.
So i don't know.
@mshikher